# iOS : decode utf8 string

Tags: ios, json, unicode, character-encoding, internationalization

I'm receiving a json data from server with some strings inside. I use `SBJson` https://github.com/stig/json-framework to get them.

However when I output some strings at `UILabel` they look like this: `\u0418\u043b\u044c\u044f\u0411\u043b\u043e\u0445` (that's Cyrillic symbols)

And it's all right with latin characters

How can I decode it into normal symbols?

Some code about getting data:

```
   NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];   
   NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:stringData error:nil];
   NSString *comments = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"comments"]];
```

String *comments* has a very special format, so I'm doing some operation like `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` ,

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` ,

`NSArray* json_fields = [comments_modified componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];`

to get a final data.

This is an example of received data after some trimming/replacing (it's `NSString* comments`):

```
"already_wow"=0;"date_created"="2012/03/1411:11:18";id=41598;name="\U0418\U043b\U044c\U044f\U0411\U043b\U043e\U0445";text="\U0438\U043d\U0442\U0435\U0440\U0435\U0441\U043d\U043e";"user_id"=1107;"user_image"="user_image/a6/6f/96/21/20111220234109510840_1107.jpg";"user_is_deleted"=0;username=IlyaBlokh;"wow_count"=0;
```

You see that fields `text` and `name` are encoded

If I display them on the view (at UILabel for example), they still look the same

Comment: @Erik Aigner, yes, my code is the same. Look my updated question - you see, I use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` configuring a string before parse it

Answer (score 0):

maybe the string returned is just the unicode string representation (ascii string), that's means not returned the content encoded with utf8, to try this with NSASCIIStringEncoding to get stringData

Comment: I make lowercase for the whole string later